# How to use a function from injected class in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

How to use a function from injected class in Aurelia? In my case, I'm calling a login() function (on the login page) and want to get the testMessage printed from Test Class. Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error in Chrome: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTestMessage' of undefined".

test.js

```
export class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.testMessage = "test";
    }

    getTestMessage() {
        return this.testMessage;
    }
}
```

login.js

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Test} from 'test';

@inject(Test)
export class LogIn { 
  constructor(test) {
    this.test = test;
  }

  login(){
    console.log("login");
    this.test.getTestMessage();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. I copied it over to a test application and it worked. The issue most likely lies in the part you didn't reveal in your question: how you are calling the `login` method.

```
<a href="#" click.delegate="login()">Login</a>
```

In my test example, the view-model injecting test and subsequent HTML view is calling the `login` method using `click.delegate`. How are you calling the method?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had a similar code, but for the button. The code works now. I haven't quite figured out the true reason, but I think I was importing 'inject' two times, what caused some issue.